# Applying Green's function in 1-D semi-infinite heat condition

Tags: calculus, heat-equation, greens-function

I have a question on how to apply Green's function in the solution of Heat equation. Assuming I want to solve
$$\frac{\partial^{2} T}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{1}{k} g(x, t)=\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} \quad \text { in } \quad 0<x<\infty, \quad t>0$$

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text { BC1: } & T(x=0, t)=f(t) \\
\text { IC: } & T(x, t=0)=F(x)
\end{array}$$
If we assume having a Dirichlet boundary condition and evaluate it into Green function solution equation, given by

$$\begin{aligned}
T(x, t)=&\left.\int_{L^{\prime}} G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right)\right|_{\tau=0} F\left(x^{\prime}\right) x^{\prime P} d x^{\prime} \\
&+\alpha \int_{\tau=0}^{t} \int_{L^{\prime}} G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right) \frac{1}{k}g\left(x^{\prime}, \tau\right) x^{\prime P} d x^{\prime} d \tau \\
&+\alpha \left\{\left.\int_{\tau=0}^{t}\left[ G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right)\right]\right|_{x^{\prime}=0} \frac{1}{k} f(\tau) d \tau\right\}
\end{aligned}$$
Where Green's function here is
$$G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right)=\frac{1}{[4 \pi \alpha(t-\tau)]^{1 / 2}}\left\{\exp \left[-\frac{\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{4 \alpha(t-\tau)}\right]-\exp \left[-\frac{\left(x+x^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{4 \alpha(t-\tau)}\right]\right\}$$

Then the third term will be $0$ which implies no effect of Dirichlet boundary condition. Why this problem arises and do I have to transform non-homogeneous boundary condition to homo-boundary condition and apply Green's function to get the result?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I was talking to you about this recently and I still don't have a clear picture of what the problem you're actually solving is. If you spell that out we should be able to help you better. I can tell you that the Green's function is adapted to the boundary condition. If you have a non-homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition then you cannot just immediately use the Green's function that is intended for homogeneous Dirichlet data. You have to adjust the problem to have homogeneous Dirichlet data first.

Comment: Okay so I have a solution of heat equation based on Green's function but when I want to apply Dirichlet boundary condition in this solution the $G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right)$ is $0$. I'm just wondering how to apply the boundary condition if I try to use this solution

Comment: Again, please write down the actual equation you're trying to solve. What kind of Dirichlet condition does it have?

Comment: @Ian That's what I'm thinking as well, I need to transform B.C. to homogeneous type.

Comment: @Ian I'll update it

Comment: Alright. Now what's this $x'^P$ thing? Also please remove the superfluous sum. And please absorb the $k$ into the $g$, there is no mathematical reason to have it outside. You could also scale $\alpha$ out by setting it equal to 1, but that's more debatable.

Comment: Alright, so now let's call the actual solution $\tilde{T}$ and write $\tilde{T}(x,t)=f(t)+T(x,t)$. Then $\tilde{T}_{xx}=T_{xx}$ and $\tilde{T}_t=f'(t)+T_t$ so if I ignore the constants then you have $T_{xx}+g=f'+T_t$ or $T_t=T_{xx}+g-f'$. Now this $T$ has a homogeneous BC, but its forcing is now $g-f'$ instead of just $g$. This works fine as long as $f$ is piecewise $C^1$.

Comment: @Ian I see. So if I don't transform BC to homogeneous I can't use this solution. Is it right?

Comment: That's essentially correct. There's a way to do it with distributions, but it's more trouble than it's worth in this situation.

Comment: Now it seems clear to me. Thanks so much for the help.